# Restricted inductive type definitions in Coq

Tags: coq

I would like to somehow limit what kind of inputs constructors are allowed to take in an inductive definition. Say I want to say define binary numbers as follows:

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
  | O : bin
  | D : bin -> bin
  | S : bin -> bin.
```

The idea here is that D doubles up a nonzero number by adding a zero at the end and S takes a number with zero as the last digit and turns the last digit into a one. This means that the following are legal numbers:

```
S 0
D (S 0)
D (D (S 0))
```

while the following would not be:

```
S (S 0)
D 0
```

Is there a way to enforce such restrictions in an inductive definition in a clean way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define what it means for a `bin` to be legal with a predicate, and then give a name to the subset of `bin`s that obey that predicate. Then you write functions with `Program Definition` and `Program Fixpoint` instead of `Definition` and `Fixpoint`. For recursive functions you'll also need a measure to prove the arguments of your functions decrease in size since the functions are not structurally recursive anymore.

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Program.

Fixpoint Legal (b1 : bin) : Prop :=
  match b1 with
  | O       => True
  | D O     => False
  | D b2    => Legal b2
  | S (S _) => False
  | S b2    => Legal b2
  end.

Definition lbin : Type := {b1 : bin | Legal b1}.

Fixpoint to_un (b1 : bin) : nat :=
  match b1 with
  | O    => 0
  | D b2 => to_un b2 + to_un b2
  | S b2 => Coq.Init.Datatypes.S (to_un b2)
  end.

Program Definition zer (b1 : lbin) := O.

Program Fixpoint succ (b1 : lbin) {measure (to_un b1)} : lbin :=
```

But [this](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.4/stdlib/Coq.Numbers.BinNums.html) simply-typed approach would probably be easier.

Comment: This seems more reasonable than the other answer. I was too lazy to write one. You could take a predicate as additional argument, but then writing numbers is annoying. You could just not care and canonicalize when needed.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with inductive-recursive definitions - but unfortunately Coq doesn't support those.

From an object-oriented programming perspective, `O`, `D` and `S` are subtypes of `bin`, and their constructor types are then definable without resorting to logical predicates, but Coq doesn't support object-oriented programming natively either.

However, Coq does have typeclasses. So what I might do is make `bin` a typeclass, and make each of the constructors a separate inductive type, each of which has an instance of the `bin` typeclass. I'm not sure what the method(s) of the typeclass would be though.